# Софт для стилизации javascript?

Tags: javascript, code-style

Какие есть программы(или ide), которые бы получали на входе js файл и на выходе выдавали его по настроенному coding standards.

Допустим есть файл, где много функций написанных кое как.
И хотелось бы их выровнять, чтобы выглядели одинаково, чтобы отступ переменных был одним и тем же(например 4 пробела с начала строки, одинаковое расположение фигурных скобок и.т.д).

```
function play_sound(file , volume) {
   var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', file);
        audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        audioElement.volume= volume;
        audioElement.play();
}

function play_sound   (file ,  volume)

                 {
   var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
 audioElement.setAttribute('src', file);
     audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
audioElement.volume= volume;
    audioElement.play();
}
```

Comment: webstorm - format code

Comment: NetBeans Alt+Shift+F

Comment: Можно воспользоваться онлайн форматорами кода. Например http://jsbeautifier.org/ . Хотя я использую WebStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка и автоматическое исправление стилей: `jscs` от Яндекса

Проверка правильности написания кода: `jshint`

Comment: Проверка стиля кодирования не то же самое, что и автоматическое приведение стилей к заданному виду.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev советую в следующий раз читать документацию и вообще побольше следить за фронтендом, а то уже фактически стандарт де-факто в мире, а вы об этом даже не слышали, там есть автоматическое форматирование

Comment: Из _вашего ответа_ этого не было видно. А если вы писали свой ответ, для профессионалов, _уже знающих_ на что способен jscs, тогда в нем вообще нет смысла. И да, я в курсе дел во фронтенде ;)